# I'm mimicking an older version and I don't know why it's not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

```
 # alexnet.py

import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization

def alexnet(width, height, lr):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 3, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=lr, name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_alexnet',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=2, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model
```

**help**

> I watched an old lecture and copied it, so I don't know why it's not working
> I know it's not working because it's an old version, but I don't know how to change it to the code that I'm using right now
> I'm using it in the visual code program

Comment: If it is an old version of python, you can simply downgrade. Or just read new syntax and convert it. Also, please provide things you have tried, as SO is not a spoonfeeding service.

Comment: @LUCK-OOB The error report is not provided, so the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: The high level module, tensorflow.contrib is being removed in version TF 2.x and it works in only TF 1.x. The official migration guide gives a 1-1 correspondence for all the functions you have used [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_note_on_slim_contriblayers). It is basically found in the Keras High Level API.